# How to get current URL when using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, onbeforeunload

I have the following code to call count_visit.php on onbeforeunload event. That works great. However, when I use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] the result is count_visit.php and not the real URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var startime = (new Date()).getTime();
window.onbeforeunload = record_visit;

function record_visit() {
    var x = (window.ActiveXObject) ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", "count_visit.php?t=" + (((new Date()).getTime() - startime) / 1000), false);
    x.send(null)
}
```

Is there a better way to get the current URL even when using the code above? Or I need to change the code above?

Comment: By "real URI" do you mean "Including the query string"?

Comment: Even w/out the query string. The above code is put under visit_length.php. So I want the result to as "visit_length.php" rather than the "count_visit.php".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want the URI of the page containing the AJAX, not the AJAX call itself - but  `count_visit.php` is the correct $SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], as this is the URI that was called by your AJAX script.

To get the page URI you need to take `window.location.href`, escape it and send it as a parameter with your AJAX call, something like

```
x.open("GET", "count_visit.php?t=" + (((new Date()).getTime() - startime) / 1000)+"&url="+escape(window.location.href), false);
```

In PHP you have to record the visit for `$_GET['url']`

Comment: instead of `escape()` you may want to be using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Yes (or even a utility function from a framework). THis is the reason I wrote "something like". I wanted the code to be instructive, not productive, and I have no knowledge of if and what JS frameworks the OP uses.

Comment: @EugenRieck it is close but I get the referrer instead of the actual URL.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "actual URL" ?  This will give you whatever is in the address bar. Have you been changing the page via AJAX or so?

Comment: @EugenRieck sorry but your code is correct. I just need to use the onload event and not the onbeforeunload event. thank you

Comment: AHA! If you want to record the visting time, do this: When setting starttime, do `pageurl=escape(window.location.href);` , on beforeunload do `x.open("GET", "count_visit.php?t=" + (((new Date()).getTime() - startime) / 1000)+"&url="+pageurl, false);`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to retrieve the full URI, you can go two ways:
First, as this is not cross-domain communication, you can concatenate two server variables

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Second way, you can change the code above and send the complete page URI to the server as additional variable of GET request.

Comment: I think you don't get me. the script above is put under visit_length.php but I get count_visit.php when I use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] instead of visit_length.php (the actual URL)

Comment: Yes, correct. Then, the second method that i've porposed suits you well. Eugen Rieck has described it in details above.

Comment: I still did not get the correct URL. The URL return is the referrer URL.